# Выровнять по центру горизонтальное меню

Tags: css, menu

Проблема в следующем, есть горизонтальное меню. В коде, который я указал, отображается как свёрнутое(спрятанное под кнопкой "MENU"), если мой пример развернуть (кнопкой "на всю страницу"), то меню раскроется полностью, и вот когда оно раскрывается все кнопки сдвигаются влево, а с права остаётся пространство. А хотелось бы сделать так что бы всё что внутри меню распределилось равномерно по центру, без дополнительных пространств и при этом сохранить адаптивность и выпадающие списки. 
Скрин проблемы(Выделено красным):http://s014.radikal.ru/i327/1701/e3/84d9f07a74c8.png
Демо меню тут:http://clickmyweb.net/demos/horizontan_menu/ 
Спасибо!

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('parent');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".parent").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#hmenu").menumaker({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "multitoggle"
      });

      $("#hmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

      var foundActive = false,
        activeElement, linePosition = 0,
        menuLine = $("#hmenu #menu-line"),
        lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

      $("#hmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          activeElement = $(this);
          foundActive = true;
        }
      });

      if (foundActive === false) {
        activeElement = $("#hmenu > ul > li").first();
      }

      defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

      defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

      menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
      menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

      $("#hmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
          activeElement = $(this);
          lineWidth = activeElement.width();
          linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
          menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
          menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
        },
        function() {
          menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
          menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
        });

    });


  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@font-face{

font-family:'SegoeUILight';
 src:url('fonts/segoeuil.eot');
 src:url('fonts/segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/segoeuil.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/segoeuil.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/segoeuil.svg#web') format('svg');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;

}
body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: SegoeUILight;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: SegoeUILight;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
#hmenu,
#hmenu ul,
#hmenu ul li,
#hmenu ul li a,
#hmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#hmenu:after,
#hmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#hmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#hmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009ae1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
#hmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#hmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#hmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#hmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#hmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#hmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#hmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#hmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#hmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #00AFFF;
}
#hmenu > ul > li.parent > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#hmenu > ul > li.parent > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#hmenu > ul > li.parent:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#hmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#hmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#hmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#hmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#hmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#hmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#hmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#hmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#hmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#hmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #00AFFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#hmenu ul ul li.parent > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#hmenu.align-right ul ul li.parent > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
#hmenu ul ul li.parent:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #00AFFF;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #hmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #hmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #hmenu.align-center > ul,
  #hmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #hmenu ul li,
  #hmenu ul ul li,
  #hmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  }
  #hmenu ul li a,
  #hmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #hmenu > ul > li,
  #hmenu.align-center > ul > li,
  #hmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #hmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul,
  #hmenu ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #hmenu > ul > li.parent > a::after,
  #hmenu ul ul li.parent > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-line {
    display: none;
  }
  #hmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #hmenu #menu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #hmenu #menu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  /* Если надо выравнить по левому краю внутри каждого блока */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/hmenu.js"></script>
  <title>Адаптивное горизонтальное меню</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Горизонтальное адаптивное выпадающее меню</h1>
      <div class="block" id='hmenu'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li class='active parent'><a href='#'>Услуги</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Что-то</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Услуги</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>О Нас</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>контент</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>О Нас</a>
          </li>

          <li><a href='#'>Контакты</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>Регистрация</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: В подменю текст кнопки должен быть по середине?

Comment: я думаю дело идет о том когда меню не на всю ширину, тогда несколько пунктов ныряют вниз а человек хочет их выровнять. Рекомендую почитать про display: flex или table, думаю flex предпочтительней

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните ваш вопрос. Он не очень понятен

Comment: Меню не на всю ширину страницы, а определённое, по центру,
 а кнопки внутри центровать, если посмотреть на меню, то от кнопки "contact" есть пространство справа. Вот хочу что бы его небыло,
 и всё было ровно.

Comment: Если раскрыть пример на полный экран, будет я думаю понятней чего я хочу

Comment: Да просто нужно явно убрать инлайн-итендент у элементов списка, а текст-алигн задать значение центр. Даже лень этим заниматься. Решается добавкой двух свойств. Давай сложнее)

Answer (score 1):

Решил вашу проблему:

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('parent');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".parent").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#hmenu").menumaker({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "multitoggle"
      });

      $("#hmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

      var foundActive = false,
        activeElement, linePosition = 0,
        menuLine = $("#hmenu #menu-line"),
        lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

      $("#hmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          activeElement = $(this);
          foundActive = true;
        }
      });

      if (foundActive === false) {
        activeElement = $("#hmenu > ul > li").first();
      }

      defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

      defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

      menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
      menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

      $("#hmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
          activeElement = $(this);
          lineWidth = activeElement.width();
          linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
          menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
          menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
        },
        function() {
          menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
          menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
        });

    });


  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@font-face{

font-family:'SegoeUILight';
 src:url('fonts/segoeuil.eot');
 src:url('fonts/segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/segoeuil.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/segoeuil.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/segoeuil.svg#web') format('svg');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;

}
body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: SegoeUILight;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: SegoeUILight;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
#hmenu,
#hmenu ul,
#hmenu ul li,
#hmenu ul li a,
#hmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#hmenu:after,
#hmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#hmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#hmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009ae1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
#hmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#hmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#hmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#hmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#hmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#hmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#hmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#hmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#hmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #00AFFF;
}
#hmenu > ul > li.parent > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#hmenu > ul > li.parent > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#hmenu > ul > li.parent:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#hmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#hmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#hmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#hmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#hmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#hmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#hmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#hmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#hmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#hmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #00AFFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#hmenu ul ul li.parent > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#hmenu.align-right ul ul li.parent > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
#hmenu ul ul li.parent:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #00AFFF;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #hmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #hmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #hmenu.align-center > ul,
  #hmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #hmenu ul li,
  #hmenu ul ul li,
  #hmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  }
  #hmenu ul li a,
  #hmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #hmenu > ul > li,
  #hmenu.align-center > ul > li,
  #hmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #hmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  #hmenu ul ul,
  #hmenu ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #hmenu > ul > li.parent > a::after,
  #hmenu ul ul li.parent > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-line {
    display: none;
  }
  #hmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #hmenu #menu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #hmenu #menu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #hmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  /* Если надо выравнить по левому краю внутри каждого блока */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/hmenu.js"></script>
  <title>Адаптивное горизонтальное меню</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Горизонтальное адаптивное выпадающее меню</h1>
      <div class="block" id='hmenu'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li class='active parent'><a href='#'>Услуги</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Что-то</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Услуги</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>О Нас</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>контент</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>О Нас</a>
          </li>

          <li><a href='#'>Контакты</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>Регистрация</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Немного не то, сейчас меню в коде, который я указал, отображается как свёрнутое(спрятанное под кнопкой "MENU"), если мой пример развернуть (кнопкой "на всю страницу"), то меню раскроется полностью, и вот когда оно раскрывается все кнопки сдвигаются влево, а с права остаётся пространство.

Comment: @CrazyKing в указаном вами примере нет такой кнопки.

Comment: Прощу прощения,подправил первый пост, теперь надеюсь понятней описал проблему..